# WCF and windows authentication not working

Tags: .net, wcf, web-config, iis-7.5

I cant get my WCF serve to windows authenticate

If I allow anonymous everything works, no errors.

I'm running .Net 3.5 on windows  2008 r2 standard SP1
IIS 7.5, if it matters VS 2010

I have used the WCF Service configuration editor to try and validate what I am doing, still no luck

I get the error after a decent wait 20-30 seconds

```
Security settings for this service require 'Anonymous' Authentication but it is not enabled for the IIS application that hosts this service. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.NotSupportedException: Security settings for this service require 'Anonymous' Authentication but it is not enabled for the IIS application that hosts this service.
```

my web.config is

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>

    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="AmjBasicHttpEndpointBinding">
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>

    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="SMS.Services.BEIMBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="SMS.Services.BEIMBehavior" name="SMS.Services.BEIM">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="AmjBasicHttpEndpointBinding"
          name="BeimServices" contract="SMS.Services.IBEIM">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>

  </system.serviceModel>
```

EDIT
the error message is on the web page. http://Servername/Directory/pageName.svc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it turns out:

> Security settings for this service require 'Anonymous' Authentication but it is not enabled for the IIS application that hosts this service.

Read the message carefully, and you'll see that you need to enable Anonymous Authentication for the IIS application hosting the service.  (In IIS configuration).

Comment: yeh ut I need it to be windows auth only, not anonymous

Comment: Why use `<security mode="None">` then?  Try `<security mode="Transport">`

Comment: that was i, ended up using TransportCredentialOnly

Answer (score 1):

WCF transport security for HTTP endpoints hosted in IIS demands that same security setting is applied on your hosting. Go to IIS manager and configure authentication for your hosting application to  Windows authentication and turn off other authentication modes.

Well as @Kieren pointed in the comment you set your security mode to `None`. So you are saying your service that you don't want any security. You should change it to `Transport` but it will also require HTTPS instead of HTTP endpoint. If you insist on HTTP and you are happy with passing security token over insecure channel you should change it to `TransportCredentialOnly`.

Comment: ywh I had already done that, as soon as I change it to windows auth i get the error message

Comment: Try to comment mex endpoint and ensure that IIS has only Windows authentication enabled for your site.

Comment: gave you a one up coz you pointed out the TransportCredentialOnly

Answer (score 0):

Have you change the config for your client side?
You client side should use the same security mechanism. And please verify that your windows credentials has been passed to server.

Comment: the error message is on the web page. http://Servername/Directory/pageName.svc
The client has the same message

Answer (score 0):

I have hosted a WCF in IIS7 in my laptop with Win7. The WCF was using SSL and only basic auth and everything were working. I migrated excactly the same wcf into IIS7 in another machine with Win server 2008 R2 and i got the same error as the post here. The soluton was to comment mex endpoint, and everything is working now. Thank you all.